# Load view with popover?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have a main view with a UINavigationController and a subview (both added through interface builder). I have a UIBarButtonItem in the navigation toolbar. When that button is clicked, I want a popover view to come up (with a table format) with options for different subviews to choose from. When a user chooses one of the subviews (by clicking a cell), the popover should fade away and the subview should change to the user's chosen view.

Those view options should be loaded from separate xib files.

I know it's a relatively complicated question, but what is the best way to do this?

I don't necessarily need code, but that would be helpful. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Check this tutorial about the popOvers:
http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/using-popoverview-ipad-app-development

Are you looking for something similar to this?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the `– loadNibNamed:owner:options:` of `NSBundle(UINibLoadingAdditions)`. Your view will be the first index object of the returned array commonly.